# How to add !important css rule to all Ant Design styles?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, wordpress, antd, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am using Ant Design with React and TypeScript to render the frontend contents of a custom admin page for a WordPress plugin project. The problem is WordPress's default styles are overriding Ant's styles which is not what I want.

After much research, I tried a suggestion which is to deregister the 'wp-admin' style but that breaks the UI of the entire page.

```
add_action('admin_init', function () {
    wp_deregister_style('wp-admin');
});
```

So the only option I can think of is to add the !important css rule to all of ant styles. But I could not find any way to do it. Ant uses inline styling so there's that. Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!